# Python selenium test - Facebook code generator XPATH

Tags: python, facebook, selenium, xpath

I'm trying to get the XPATH for Code Generator field form (Facebook) in order to fill it (of course before I need to put a code with "numbers").

In Chrome console when I get the XPATH I get:

> //*[@id="approvals_code"]

And then in my test I put:

> elem = driver.find_element_by_xpath("//*[@id='approvals_code']")
>
> if elem: elem.send_keys("numbers")
>         elem.send_keys(Keys.ENTER)

With those I get:

> StaleElementReferenceException: Message: stale element reference: element is not attached to the page document

What means wrong field name. Does anyone know how to properly get a XPATH?

Answer (score 0):

This error usually comes if element is not present in the DOM.

Or may be element is in iframe.

Comment: This is input field: 

<input type="text" class="inputtext" id="approvals_code" name="approvals_code" tabindex="1" autocomplete="off" placeholder="Text code" aria-label="Text code"> –